# model not propagating to controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model hook in my Route object that looks like this:

```
model: function(params) {
    // return an active filter for activities on given date
    return this.store.filter('activity',function(activity){     
        var itemDate = new Date(activity.get('start_time'));
        itemDate = moment(itemDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        return itemDate === params.on_date;
    });
}
```

The route's `currentModel` gets populated with the `DS.FilteredRecordArray` with all the appropriate values set but for some reason the model never gets passed to the controller and therefore my template's `{{#each}} {{/each}}` remains empty.

I created a hack where I set added the following to the route:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model',this.get('currentModel'));
}
```

This actually works when you load the controller the first time but then goes into an infinite loop when you `transitionTo` to the route. Ahh well, it was a hack anyway. Does anyone know how I can get this working the "Ember way"?

Comment: Could you post the code where you set `currentModel`?

Comment: I never actually set `currentModel` explicitly. I just assumed this was part of the Ember dark arts. I simply return an object from the `model` hook in the Route and currentModel gets populated (with what I'd expect to be in the `model` property.

Comment: I have never heard of that myself, maybe it's an internal thing? In any case I'm not sure why you would need that since the model is passed into the `setupController` function as a parameter. Thus all you should need to do is `controller.set('content', model);`. I'll also add that as an answer - let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to populate the content of your controller with your model (the result of your `filter` function) like this:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('content', model);
}
```

Though this should also be the default behavior and I don't think you need to explicitly define that.

Comment: That should be the default behaviour and that's what's got me perplexed as this wasn't happening. If you're interested I solved this a different way ... you can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227183/using-set-on-an-array/19236283

Comment: So this fixed it? Normally you do not have to explicitly specify it, but maybe it has to do with how you set up your resource/route in your Router?

Comment: Yes. Still a bit mysterious as I hadn't thought i'd done anything differently but as long as I have a working solution I'll manage to keep on keeping on. :)

Comment: Glad it works. Do you mind accepting the solution so the question doesn't show up as unanswered?

Comment: I had held off because your suggestion actually wasn't the solution to my problem. I upvoted because I felt your suggestion was reasonable and I appreciated the input. I will find the time to put my final solution in over the next week I hope. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ah I see - I'd be interested to see your final solution. I'm glad you got it to work