# Using set() on an array

Tags: ember.js

I have an EmberArray that caches all activities at the day level. Therefore if I've pulled activities from the server for 1st July it will be found in `activitiesByDay['2013-07-01']`. My problem is how to get() and set() these array items so that I can take advantage of Ember's Run Loop and data binding properties.

Here's the full code:

```
module.exports = App.ActivitiesRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
    onDate: null,
    actionList: Ember.ArrayController.create(),
    activitiesByDate: Ember.Array,
    activitiesOnDate: function() {
        return this.get('activitiesByDate')[this.get('onDate')].content;
    }.property('activitiesByDate','onDate'),
    if (!this.get('activitiesByDate')[params.on_date]) {
        this.set('activities', this.store.find('activity', {on_date: params.on_date}));
        this.get('activitiesByDate')[params.on_date] =
            this.store.filter('activity',function(activity){        
                var itemDate = new Date(activity.get('start_time'));
                itemDate = moment(itemDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                return itemDate === params.on_date;
            });
    }
```

As you can see, the line item which says ...

> this.get('activitiesByDate')[params.on_date] =

is a problem because I'm making changes without letting Ember know. The problem is I can't find a way to use Ember's `set()` on an array who's keys are dates of the format "YYYY-MM-DD". This key structure, I believe, requires me to use Javascript's bracket notation versus dot notation that Ember should handle.

---- UPDATE ----

I have updated the `ActivitiesRoute` a little so that the `activitiesByDate` is an object rather than an Ember.Array. I have also changed all setters/getters to the properties of this object to use Embers get/set()`

```
App.ActivitiesRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
    onDate: null,
    activitiesByDate: Ember.Object.create(),
    activitiesOnDate: function() {
        return this.get('activitiesByDate.' + this.get('onDate'));
    }.property('activitiesByDate'),

    model: function(params) {
        this.set('onDate', params.on_date);
        // check if the given date has activities already loaded and if not then load it
        // if it does then do NOT reload. In the case of wanting a refresh use the refreshDate() method
        if (!this.get('activitiesByDate')[params.on_date]) {
            console.log('getting activities for: ' + params.on_date);
            this.set('activities', this.store.find('activity', {on_date: params.on_date})); // go get the dates from Server
            this.set('activitiesByDate.' + [params.on_date], this.store.filter('activity',function(activity){       
                var itemDate = new Date(activity.get('start_time'));
                itemDate = moment(itemDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                return itemDate === params.on_date;
            }));
        }

        return true;
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('activitiesByDate',this.get('activitiesByDate'));
    }
```

The `activitiesByDate` object seems to work fine. Here's an example of what it's state looks like after having gone to three separate dates:

[image]

Looking inside these objects I can see that they contain the right amount of activities so that part looks good. Unfortunately my computed property -- `activitiesOnDate` is not being updated outside of when I hit reload in the browser.

Comment: have you tried notifying the system by hand calling `this.get('activitiesByDate').enumerableContentDidChange()` after setting the new item in the arraycontroller: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/v1.0.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/enumerable.js#L927

Comment: Ahhh. I did try and 'touch' it to signal the update but didn't know about the enumerableContentDidChange() method. Let me try that again. I think that might be a very workable solution.

Comment: Well I'm at a loss. Still liking your suggestion but when I try and implement it it complains that `activitiesByDate` doesn't have an enumerableContentDidChange() property. Yet looking at the debugger I can see clearly that it has the `Enumerable` mixin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `set('someProperty.' + dynamicProperty, value)` and `get('someProperty.' + dynamicProperty)`, you will have what you want. In your case:

**Getting the filtered result**

```
//Instead of
this.get('activitiesByDate')[this.get('onDate')]

// You would use 
this.get('activitiesByDate.' + this.get('onDate'));
```

**Setting the filtered result**

```
// Instead of
var filtered = this.store.filter('activity',function(activity){        
    var itemDate = new Date(activity.get('start_time'));
    itemDate = moment(itemDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    return itemDate === params.on_date;
});

this.get('activitiesByDate')[params.on_date] = filtered;


// You would use 
var filtered = this.store.filter('activity',function(activity){        
    var itemDate = new Date(activity.get('start_time'));
    itemDate = moment(itemDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    return itemDate === params.on_date;
});

// if some key change, notify the entire property
Ember.propertyWillChange(this, 'activitiesByDate');
this.set('activitiesByDate.' + params.on_date, filtered);
Ember.propertyDidChange(this, 'activitiesByDate');
```

Comment: Ok, let me check that. I had the impression that an array subscript of "2013-09-25" couldn't be referenced through dot notation, only [] subscripting and I tried what you suggested using that syntax to no avail.

Comment: I think that your data structure is, an object where the keys is the date, and the values is an array like (DS.FilteredRecordArray). For instance: `{ '2013-05-05': [{ id: 1, ...}, ...] }`. Right?

Comment: `activitiesByDate` is an Ember.Array. BTW, I tried your solution at the debug console and it does seem to work however I'm still not getting the results I would expect in my actual code execution. Need to dig into this some more.

Comment: I think that using an object is more easy, like you have said using `array[someThing] = value`, just works with indexes. If you want to set and get data using strings you need to use a plain js object. Be carefull because here `activitiesByDate: Ember.Array` you are setting the `activitiesByDate` to the Ember.Array class, this isn't a new instance of an array ...

Comment: I had wondered about the Ember.Array, glad to take your advice on moving to an object. Unfortunately I'm still struggling. I've updated the question with the latest information. In a nutshell ... I'm still not getting any reaction from my computed property when the underlying property changes.

Comment: The problem is that your computed property is dependent of `activitiesByDate`, but the current value changed is for example  `activitiesByDate.2012-05-01`. You will need to manually notify the `activitiesByDate` property when something changes. Give a look in the updated answer. And in this fiddle to see a minimalistic sample http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/urT3X/

Comment: One last thing to note ... in my code example I had been using a computed property but these are only updated when they are explicitly referenced and therefore the hook to set the Controller's property being put inside the computed property was a problem. I changed it to an observer and then did everything that @Marcio suggested and it I'm as happy as a plum (assuming that plums are pretty happy).